# Receive Json with multiple content in Post API

Tags: c#, .net

I have a Rest API in .Net Framework 4.8 and I need to receive different json formats\content in the same method Post.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("")]
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] DataPost dataPost)
{ .. }
```

The `DataPost` class has the same beginning for all formats, which serves as an identifier, but the content within "items" can change

Examples of content:

example 1

```
{
  "client": "clientName",
  "process": "ApiProcess",
  "environment": "dev",
  "items":
  {
    "target": "dev",
    "content": "abc"
  }
}
```

example 2

```
{
  "client": "clientName",
  "process": "ApiProcess",
  "environment": "dev",
  "items":
  {
    "alpha": "1",
    "beta": "2"
    "version": "0.9"
  }
}
```

DataPost Model

```
public class Root
{
  public string client { get; set; }
  public string process { get; set; }
  public string environment { get; set; }
  public Items items { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible create `Items` as a simple String and then convert it to an object considering the content of `Process`?

I tried to create an `Items` model with all the data possibilities, but I didn't like this alternative

Comment: You can use a `Dictionary<string,>` instead. It would be a lot simpler and definitely more RESTful if you used different routes for different URLs. It seems that `Items` is the actual entity and `client`, `process` etc are just metadata that could even be stored in headers. The REST architecture uses a different resource for each entity, specified by its URL. Different HTTP actions (POST, PUT, etc) are used to modify that entity.

Comment: At the moment I cannot create new routes, as the objective is to use a centralized Post method for N requests

Comment: That sounds like an attempt to centralize what doesn't need centralizing - controllers deal with *specific* resources. Metadata and cross-cutting concerns are implemented using middleware. You could write a custom binder that deserializes `items` and stores it in a property BUT then you'd have to check what that property holds and take different actions based on its value. That's what ASP.NET's routing and controllers already did for you

Comment: From your previous comment I'm wondering why you insist on working against the framework? Just create a second route and solve your problem almost instantly. Be a good programmer, be lazy.

Comment: The initial premise of this development was precisely to centralize all types of inputs at a single point, creating a kind of tunnel for several different requests. After this point, there are other dependent services and changing this premise would impact other processes, so I have no way to change this.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few different approaches you can take here.
First of all, if you're using `Newtonsoft.Json`, you can simply use `dynamics` in order to achieve what you're looking for.
If you change your model to:

```
public class Root
{
  public string client { get; set; }
  public string process { get; set; }
  public string environment { get; set; }
  public dynamic items { get; set; }
}
```

`Newtonsoft.Json` will correctly deserialize the object and allow you to access your `items` with a simple `items.target` or `items.alpha` depending on the JSON you received.

On the other hand, if you're using the native `System.Text.Json`, `dynamics` have not been implemented. You can still use the `dynamic` type for `items` in your model and deserialization will be performed correctly, but you won't be able to access the properties using `items.alpha` notation.
`System.Text.Json` will return `items` as a boxed `JsonElement`.

In this case, your most probably going to want to go with `Dictionary<string, string>` as it seems that all of your values are wrapped in `"` anyway. It's not ideal, but it would allow you to access the properties of either model using keywords.

For this, simply change your model to:

```
public class Root
{
  public string client { get; set; }
  public string process { get; set; }
  public string environment { get; set; }
  public Dictionary<string, string> items { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT: You can find a very complete blog post regarding this issue [here.](https://code-maze.com/csharp-deserialize-json-into-dynamic-object/)